# How does auto work in c++?

Tags: c++

From what I have read about "auto" declaration is that it acquires the datatype depending on the return value of the function.

```
int main()
{
    vector <int>  v;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    v.push_back(i);
    auto it=max_element(v.begin(),v.end());
    cout<<*it;
}
```

What is wrong in this code? What are all place where I can use "auto"?

I am getting an error>>
"it does not name a type"

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "What is wrong in this code?" [Nothing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3541e2d40dde563a) as far as I can tell. (Apart from `using namespace std;` of course)

Comment: Sorry for the delay...Error message is " 'it' is not declared in the scope"..

Comment: and also "it does not name a type"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**auto** is not limited to the return values of functions, but to mostly everything where the compiler can actually deduce the type of a variable without you having to tell it explicitly. So:

```
  std::vector< std::string >::iterator it = myVector.begin();  // C++98 -> c'mon compiler, you know what the returned value of begin is, why do I have to write it?
  auto it = myVector.begin();  // C++11 -> ah, that's much more convenient
                                 // note that the type of it is still the same, you just didn't have to write it down
```

In C++14, auto can also be used for the return types of functions, so

```
// c++98
std::vector< std::string > createAFancyStringVector()
{
  std::vector< std::string > vec;
...
  return vec;
}

// c++14
auto createAFancyStringVector()
{
  // same function body, the compiler deduces the return type from the return statement
}
```

For in-depth reading on this, I recommend Scott Meyer's 'Effective Modern C++', chapter 2.

Ah, and to answer the question: your code looks fine, there's no other place where using auto makes sense (you could use auto instead of int in the loop, but that brings no real benefit)

**Additional Info**: since auto is a C++11 feature, it obviously depends on a compiler that supports it and has this feature enabled. Namely that would be e.g. Clang > 3.3 or GCC >4.3 (with compiler flag -std=c++11) or VC++ 2013 / 2015

Comment: Still it doesn't answer.Why I am getting error in my code..

Comment: Hmm, the code looks ok and compiles fine for me. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that you're compiling with C++1x support? I.e. is the -std compiler option set correctly to -std=c++11 or -std=c++14?

Comment: Correct: the code does compile with the `std=c++14` (or `-std=c++11`) switch, but it gives those errors without. @mvd, you should add that to the answer for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: Yes, good point. I added the info.